# C# ArgumentNullException type or namespace could not be found. VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, argumentnullexception

Part Of **My Code**:

```
 public void Move(Point newLocation)
    {
        if (newLocation == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("newLocation");

        Move(newLocation.X, newLocation.Y);
    }
```

**I get this as a Error**:

> The type or namespace name 'ArgumentNullException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
>   assembly reference?)

Is there something wrong with my c# code. Could this be a VS Code C# support extension bug?

I am a beginner to c# please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ArgumentNullException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=netframework-4.8) is in the "System" [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/).  So either fully-qualify the name,

```
throw new System.ArgumentNullException("newLocation");
```

or add

```
using System;
```

to the top of your C# file or your namespace.